# ¿Qué imagen Docker puedo usar para instalar Wordpress con plugin Duplicator?

Tags: php, wordpress, zip, docker

Muy buenas :)

Solicito un cable .. :

- Instalo Wordpress y MySQL (oficiales) en Docker y Docker Machine (Mac).
- Instalo 1 plugin, para mi imprescindible, DUPLICATOR.
- Cuando ejecuto el primer PACKAGE, me da el siguiente mensaje:

> PHP SUPPORT : Zip Archive Enabled : FAIL.

- Buscando, comentan, obviamente que mi versión de PHP Tiene que tener habilitada la opción Zip Archive.

Mis preguntas son:

- ¿Qué versiones concretas de wordpress y mysql en Docker Hub tengo que utilizar, SIN tener que CAMBIAR la DockerFile y cambiar las especificaciones?
- ¿Cómo debo emplearlas?
- ¿Me podéis indicar alguna combinación ya preparada sin este tipo de problemas y sin problemas de seguridad ?

Hasta ahora, con las repos oficiales, lo hacía así:

```
docker run —name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mysql 

docker run --name some-wordpress --link some-mysql:mysql –p 80 -d wordpress
```

Comment: El contenedor de wordpress está basado en el de PHP, con lo que incluye scripts para que puedas añadir fácilmente las extensiones que necesites al dockerfile. Creo que es mejor que te mires ésto que intentar encontrar el contenedor perfecto que tenga justo lo que necesitas.

Comment: Coincido con ChemaCortes, no vas a encontrar el contenedor perfecto. Posiblemente con armar un Dockerfile basado en los que estás usando y agregando la línea para instalar el paquete en cuestión estés. Si tienes problemas al ir por ese lado, no dudes en preguntar.

Answer (score 1):

Si no deseas armar tu propia imagen, es decir quieres usar la imagen como viene de [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), podrías utilizar [Imagen oficial de Wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/)

También puede encontrar imagenes como esta [rednut/php-resque-runner](https://hub.docker.com/r/rednut/php-resque-runner/) que tiene muchas extensiones instaladas (incluyendo zip).

Pero lo cierto que hacer una recomendación sobre una imagen en particular, no deja de ser una opinión.